# Android SeekBar with HorizontalScrollView

Tags: java, android, seekbar, horizontalscrollview

I have a SeekBar inside HorizontalScrollView.
When moving the SeekBar scale sometimes it scrolls the HorizontalScrollView.

Any alternatives for SeekBar when using with HorizontalScrollView ???

Thanks!

Comment: tel me ur requriement corrlectly,iam notgeeting ur point,can u xplian clearly

Answer (score 5):

you can set metode on seekbar's touch event like this .

```
SEEKBAR.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

                if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
                {
                HLISTVIEW.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```